# Different CPU fan speed after sleep and reboot but .../hwmon3/pwm1 values stay the same

Tags: thinkpad, fan

I'm stuck on a problem with inconsistent CPU fan RPMs on Thinkpad T540p. I use thinkfan on Ubuntu 20.04 to control fan speed. It uses thinkpad_acpi which in turn changes values of `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1`.

After reboot these are the values in hwmon files - these reflect level 1 in thinkpad_acpi so the lowest fan speed of 2067 RPM:

```
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1 = 36
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/pwm1_enable = 1
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_input ~ 2067
```

After going into sleep and waking up - same level 1 but this time 1600 RPM:

```
/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/fan1_input ~ 1600
```

Other values stay the same. The correct and desired value for level 1(36) is 1600 RPM. It is quiet and sufficient. It's the same on Windows on idle.

Why do relation between values in `pwm1` and `fan1_input` is inconsistent and how can I fix it so that lvl1 = 1600 RPM on idle after reboot?